# Explain in detail this shift function, I'm not sure how to understand this

Tags: r

Could someone please explain in English the logic behind what this function does.

```
shift <- function(x,n) {
  c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n))
}
```

Comment: It removes first `n` elements of `x` and then adds `n` number of `NA` at the end of `x`.

Comment: @d.b., post as answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shift <- function(x, n)` defines a function named `shift` that takes two arguments `x` and `n`.

`c()` is an `R` function that combines vectors. In this case, it combines `x[-(seq(n))]` and `rep(NA, n)` into a single vector.

`x[-(seq(n))]` is a way of removing elements from `x` based on indices (negative sign specifies removal). `seq(n)` is another `R` function that generates integers from `1` to `n`. Basically, `x[-(seq(n))]` removes the first `n` elements of `x`.

`rep(NA, n)` just repeats `NA` (special constant that stands for 'Not Available' in `R`) `n` times.

The end result is that `shift` removes first `n` elements of `x` and then adds `n` number of `NA` at the end of `x`.